# How do I remove certain label values from the priceline in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator

I'm a total beginner and have managed to put together this simple script that calculates 5 moving averages and a visual cross label each time one of the MAs crosses another. What I would like to achieve is a way of removing the value of the cross labels from the priceline, so that only the MA and instrument price values are shown. At the moment, the effect of having all the various values all shown together is visually confusing.
Many thanks in advance,

Tom.

```
//@version=5
indicator('MA 51/126/202', overlay=true)
ma202 = ta.sma(close, 202)
ma126 = ta.sma(close, 126)
ma51 = ta.sma(close, 51)
ma15 = ta.sma(close, 15)
ma5 = ta.sma(close, 5)
plot(ma51, title='MA 51', style=plot.style_line, color=color.new(color.blue, 65), linewidth=3)
plot(ma126, title='MA 126', style=plot.style_line, color=color.new(#0033ff, 85), linewidth=2)
plot(ma202, title='MA 202', style=plot.style_line, color=color.new(#0d47a1, 0), linewidth=4)
plot(ma15, title='MA 15', style=plot.style_line, color=color.new(#fbc02d, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(ma5, title='MA 5', style=plot.style_line, color=color.new(#b2ebf2, 0), linewidth=2)

plot(ta.crossover(ma51, ma202) ? ma202 : na, title='Golden Cross', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), linewidth=5)
plot(ta.crossunder(ma51, ma202) ? ma202 : na, title='Death Cross', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=5)
plot(ta.crossover(ma51, ma126) ? ma126 : na, title='Cross Up 1', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), linewidth=4)
plot(ta.crossover(ma126, ma51) ? ma126 : na, title='Cross Down 1', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=4)
plot(ta.crossover(ma126, ma202) ? ma126 : na, title='Cross Up 2', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), linewidth=4)
plot(ta.crossover(ma202, ma126) ? ma126 : na, title='Cross Down 2', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=4)
plot(ta.crossover(ma5, ma15) ? ma15 : na, title='Cross Up 3', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), linewidth=3)
plot(ta.crossover(ma15, ma5) ? ma15 : na, title='Cross Down 3', style=plot.style_cross, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `plot` function have a `display` parameter. You can use it to decide where you want to display the results of the `plot` function:

> **display (input plot_display)** Controls where the plot's information is displayed. Display options support addition and subtraction, meaning that using `display.all - display.status_line` will display the plot's information everywhere except in the script's status line. `display.price_scale + display.status_line` will display the plot only in the price scale and status line. When `display` arguments such as `display.price_scale` have user-controlled chart settings equivalents, the relevant plot information will only appear when all settings allow for it. Possible values: `display.none`, `display.pane`, `display.data_window`, `display.price_scale`, `display.status_line`, `display.all`. Optional. The default is `display.all`.

Comment: Thank you @mr_statler! I added the line "display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line" to the plot code, et voila problem solved. Much appreciated.